# Fastest way to retrieve HTML from PHP, shared-memory?

Tags: php, ajax, performance

Im trying to optimize the response time of a PHP file which retrieves 10KB of HTML to an AJAX request. There are however a lot of these requests, and quickly add up to a lot of data transfer.

The AJAX calls PHP via

```
$("#div1").load("file"+var+".php")
```

And the PHP contains the HTML to be loaded, but it first authenticates the request.

```
<?php
session_start();
... authentication ...
?>

<html>
<body>
10 KB content
</body>
</html>
```

But I was thinking if the 10 KB were already in shared memory, the response time will be faster. Something done via Shmop or APCu.

```
<?php
session_start();
... authentication ...

$shm_data = unserialize(shmop_read($shm_id, 0, $len)); 
echo $shm_data
?>
```

So Im wondering if retrieving content via shmop is faster than putting the content inside the PHP file. Thanks.

Comment: First rule of performance optimisation: 1. measure 2. optimise

Comment: I am sorry but I do not believe that anybody in the right mind would give a 2MB HTML web page. Seems rather excessive as it is unusable.

Comment: Yes Im sorry its much less, something around 10kb, Ill edit the question. But the reason I put 2MB is because theres a lot of AJAX each with 10kb that in short periods of time transfer around 2MB.

Comment: 2MB of dynamic data? Really even if in short bursts. Surely most is static stuff.

Comment: @EdHeal I just tested Twitter.com with a cleared cache and got 3.4 MB transferred. Facebook was 2.9 MB. NYTimes.com was 2.4 MB. Modern webdev easily hits megabytes.

Comment: Most of that is images/static content. What proportion is AJAX and the bit for the individual user. PS: AJAX usually does POST requests and therefore not caches

Comment: Well is there any way to retrieve the data faster? Part of the content also contains *private* images which Im unsure whether to store in shared memory or call them inside the PHP via <img src="pimg.php?i=pb1.jpg" />